# Attempting to make a variable phase shift circuit

Tags: phase-shift

I'm attempting to construct the variable phase shift circuit from [this video](https://youtu.be/FHXZ9C914S0?t=130) (link takes you to the circuit diagram of it) except that I am using a 1 uF capacitor in place of the .022 uF capacitor. I have been unable to get it to work and I wanted to check if that change was what was causing the issue or if I have made a mistake in my construction of it?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Did you change the value for a reason, or just because that's what you happened to have?
Changing a capacitor in a frequency dependent circuit by a factor of 50 is going to get very different results.

Comment: >unable to get it to work. What did you do?

Comment: @GodJihyo because it was what I had

Comment: @Antonio51 I constructed the circuit as described and I get an incredibly small voltage and noisy signal, nothing like the clean phase shift as shown in the video.

Comment: @YaGoiRoot I thought as much. Are the rest of the components the same as in the video, or more of 'what you had'?
If constructed properly that capacitor being larger wouldn't cause a low, noisy signal, so something else must be going on. We would need to see a schematic at least, and pictures if possible of the circuit you built, also voltage measurements would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

DC quiet point is ok.

For showing the "phased" signal, I used a scope with (x,y) inputs (x=generator, y=output signal) and made what is called a "Lissajous" picture.

Phase can be calculated or measured as usual.

I make a simulation for the original circuit (@1000 Hz, 0 < Rpot < 5k)

[image]

Then a simulation @20 Hz with the 1uF capacitor ... variable resistor is now 50k.

[image]